# Почему не срабатывает js, на добавленных элементах?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть [код](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmNRbe). К сожалению, кнопки добавления и удаления на добавленных additional item-ах не срабатывают(хотя на item все в порядке). Посмотрел в консоли и заметил, что судя по всему проблема в том,что на добавленные элементы не вешается `listener`. Не понимаю почему так происходит. Как в данной ситуации заставить работать кнопки добавленных элементов? 
Во избежания закрытия и недоверия некоторых пользователей к ресурсу codepen, представленному выше ссылкой, опублику тут код(а то ведь так и вопрос зарубят...)

html:

```
<ul id="item_ul">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="remove-item">×</a>
    <a href="#" class="add-item">+</a>
    <a href="#">ITEM</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.remove-item{
  background-color: red;
  color:white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1px 5px;
}
li{
  margin: 5px;
}

.add-item {
  background-color: blue;
  color:white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1px 5px;
}
ul li a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: black;
}
```

js:

```
var $item_ul = $('#item_ul');
$('.remove-item', $item_ul).on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('li').remove(); /* remove item */
});
$('.add-item', $item_ul).on('click', function() {
  itemAdd();
});

function itemAdd() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML =
    '<a href="#" class="remove-item" title="Remove this item">×</a>\n' +
    '<a href="#" class="add-item" title="Add item">+</a>\n' +
    '<a href="#">\n' +
    'ADDITIONAL ITEM\n' +
    '</a>\n';
  document.getElementById('item_ul').appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: @АлексейШиманский и в чем мой вопрос некорректен? код,который можно посмотреть приведен,проблема описана, личные предположения о причинах проблемы описаны. что не так?

Comment: Не вижу код.... вижу ссылку на какой-то левый ресурс...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский этот "левый" ресурс - codepen.io аналог jsfiddle. код представлен там для того,чтобы можно было без труда его запустить и посмотреть проблему. или на стеке запрещено на него ссылаться?

Comment: На стеке принято код располагать в вопросе,  а ссылку оставить как дополнение. Казалось бы вы задали 78 вопросов, год на ресурсе, но так и не знаете как правильно это делается и для чего.

Comment: ок. добавил код

Comment: `$("#item_ul").on("click", ".remove-item", function(){ ... });`

Comment: @Igor ваш вариант отработал. вы не могли бы продублировать его в ответ,чтобы я его выбрал и закрыл вопрос?и еще, вас не затруднит хотя бы в 2 словах объяснить,почему мой вариант не работал как надо?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как Вы сами заметили, в момент назначения клик-обработчики навешиваются только на те элементы, которые существуют. Чтобы обработчики срабатывали и для элементов, созданных в дальнейшем, навесим обработчик на родительский элемент, сузив контекст обработчика, указав дополнительный селектор вторым параметром функции `on` - делегирование *(что-то я деепричастиями увлекся в последнем предложении :))*:

```
$("#item_ul").on("click", ".remove-item", function(){ 
  ... 
});
$("#item_ul").on("click", ".add-item", function(){ 
  ... 
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: то есть,если указывать селектор первым параметром как  у меня,то оно не будет срабатывать на только появившихся элементах?

Comment: @Iga У Вас клик-обработчик прикрепляется к элементам, выбранным селектором `".remove-item"`, - естественно, только тем, которые существуют на момент назначения обработчика. С дополнительным условием, что эти элементы должны быть внутри элементов, попавших в селектор `$('#item_ul')` - естественно, такой всего один. В ответе, обработчик прикрепляется на `$('#item_ul')` с указанием, что он должен выполняться для элементов, удовлетворяющих выборке `".remove-item"`.

Comment: понял, спасибо)